# Executing remote command using expect from C++

Tags: c++, c++11, ssh, tcl

I wrote some code to execute remote commands over ssh, using expect, from c++. The code works but is a bit of a mess of c / c++ since there doesn't seem to be an idiomatic way to achieve much of what I wanted in pure c++. I appreciate that there are nominally some security concerns with the way I'm using passwords, but these aren't a concern for my use cases.

**remote_commmand.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>

struct RemoteException : public std::runtime_error {
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};

void remote_command(const std::string &host, const std::string &user, const std::string &password, const std::string &cmd);
```

**remote_command.cpp**

```
#include "remote_command.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using std::string;

namespace {

const char* expect_template =
"set timeout 60\n"
"spawn ssh %s@%s %s\n"
"expect {\n"
"   \"*yes/no*\"\n"
"   {\n"
"       send \"yes\\r\"\n"
"       exp_continue\n"
"   }\n"
"   \"*?assword:*\"\n"
"   {\n"
"       send -- \"%s\\r\"\n"
"       send -- \"\\r\"\n"
"       expect eof\n"
"   }\n"
"}\n";

class TempFile {

public:
    explicit TempFile(const char* contents){
        file_name = std::tmpnam(nullptr);
        std::ofstream f(file_name.c_str(), std::ios::out);
        if(!f.write(contents, std::strlen(contents))){
            throw std::runtime_error("ofstream");
        }
    }

    ~TempFile(){
        std::remove(file_name.c_str());
    }

    TempFile(TempFile &other) = delete;
    TempFile& operator=(TempFile &other) = delete;

    std::string file_name;
};

}


void remote_command(const string &host, const string &user, const string &password, const string &cmd){
    std::vector<char> formatted_cmd;
    const std::size_t formatted_size = std::strlen(expect_template) + host.size() + user.size() + password.size() + cmd.size();
    formatted_cmd.resize(formatted_size);

    const std::size_t res = std::snprintf(&formatted_cmd[0], formatted_size, expect_template, user.c_str(), host.c_str(), cmd.c_str(), password.c_str());

    if (res <= 0 || res >= formatted_size ){
        throw RemoteException("infsufficient size for snprintf");
    }

    TempFile tempfile(&formatted_cmd[0]);

    int r = execl("/usr/bin/expect", "-f", tempfile.file_name.c_str(), (char *)0);
    if (r == -1){
        throw RemoteException(string("execl") + std::strerror(errno) );
    }
}
```

**example usage**

```
remote_command("my-host", "user", "pw", "/path/to/my/script.sh");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Consider using raw literals

Your `expect_template` is a prime candidate to be written as a raw string literal:

```
const char* expect_template =
R"(set timeout 60
spawn ssh %s@%s %s
expect {
   "*yes/no*"
   {
       send "yes\r"
       exp_continue
   }
   "*?assword:*"
   {
       send -- "%s\r"
       send -- "\r"
       expect eof
   }
}
)";
```

I may have missed something in the editing, but the basic idea is pretty simple: you don't use escapes at all, just insert exactly what you want the string to contain (including new-lines).

Given an `R` immediately before the quote, the compiler treats the content as a raw literal. The opening delimiter is the quote, other optional "stuff", and an open paren. The closing delimiter is a close paren, the same optional stuff, and the close quote. In your case, the optional "stuff" isn't needed--you'd use it if you might need to include `)"` as part of your string. In that case, you might have something like `R"<^>(` at the beginning so the end of the string would only be signaled by `)<^>"` (the exact content doesn't matter a whole lot--you just have to be sure it's something that can't occur inside the string).

#### Use of `.c_str()`

C++98/03 required that you use `s.c_str()` when passing `s` to a stream's constructor or `open` member function. C++11 eliminated that requirement, so you can just pass the string directly.

#### Passing strings as parameters

Absent a reason to do otherwise, I'd at least consider passing `std::string const &` as the parameter to (for one example) `TempFile::TempFile`. This can simplify some of the content a little, and still lets you pass a C-style string when/if you want:

```
explicit TempFile(std::string const &contents) {
    file_name = std::tmpnam(nullptr);
    std::ofstream f(file_name);
    if(!(f << contents)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("writing ofstream");
    }
}
```

#### Use of snprintf

You might want to consider using a stringstream instead of snprintf. This does ease at least a few parts of the job, although it's not exactly perfect either.

```
std::ostringstream s;

s << 
R("set timeout 60
spawn ssh )" << user << "@" host << " " command << R"(
expect {
   "*yes/no*"
   {
       send "yes\r"
       exp_continue
   }
   "*?assword:*"
   {    
       send -- ")"
<< password << R"(\r"
        send -- "\r"
        expect eof
    }
}
)";

TempFile f(s.str());
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the raw literals. I looked into using them, but the fact they could be used multiline totally passed me by.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something basic_ofstream::write must take a `const char*` not a `std::string` so I still need the `c_str()` at that call site.

Comment: @cloakedlearning: Oops--yes, you do. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: No problem. Seems like an odd omission to me. Hopefully `string_view` will help clean things up a bit in c++17

Comment: @cloakedlearning: Modified code to do it the obvious way.

Comment: Yup, that's certainly a better approach, thanks. I think you're missing some parens though - the `!` has higher precedence than the `<<`.

Comment: @cloakedlearning: Good point.